# Como evitar que usuários diferentes vejam a mesma informação?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Fiz um formulário no qual o usuário informa um código de cliente e faz uma pesquisa em um banco de dados, o qual retorna as informações deste cliente na mesma pagina html do formulário. Porem, se outro usuário acessar a mesma página ele vê o resultado das pesquisas do usuário anterior. Como faço para que o formulário e as informações não sejam compartilhadas? Ou seja, cada usuário visualizaria somente as informações que ele pediu, e não a de outros usuários.